# Material determination of submeshes through raycasting in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm attempting to place props randomly on a mesh. The mesh has 2 materials and I'd like to only place the props on one of the materials. I'm currently doing this through raycasting, determining the material at the point hit and if the material is correct I place a prop at that point. I'm having an issue where the material is being determined incorrectly and I'm not certain why. Code is below.
using UnityEngine;

```
public class BoundingBoxTry : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public MeshFilter meshFilter;
private Renderer rend;
private Mesh mesh;
private Bounds bnds;
private float nextX, nextZ, maxX, minX, maxZ, minZ;
public GameObject rayOrigin;
public GameObject propPreFab;
private MeshCollider thisCollider;
void Start () {
    thisCollider = GetComponentInChildren<MeshCollider>();
    rend = GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>();
    mesh = GetComponentInChildren<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
    bnds = rend.bounds;
}

void Update () {
    nextX = Random.Range(0, bnds.size.x);   
    nextZ = Random.Range(0, bnds.size.z);   
    nextX = nextX-bnds.size.x/2;
    nextZ = nextZ-bnds.size.z/2;
    nextX = bnds.center.x-nextX;
    nextZ = bnds.center.z-nextZ;
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    Vector3 randomCoord = new Vector3(nextX, 0, nextZ);
    rayOrigin.transform.position = new Vector3(nextX, 100, nextZ);
    bool didHit = Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin.transform.position, -new Vector3(0, 1, 0), out hit);
    int vertCounter = 0;

    if(didHit && hit.collider == thisCollider){
        for (int sMC = 0; sMC < mesh.subMeshCount; sMC++)
        {
            int[] subMesh = mesh.GetTriangles(sMC);
            vertCounter = vertCounter + subMesh.Length;             
            if(hit.triangleIndex < vertCounter){
                if(rend.sharedMaterials[sMC] == rayOrigin.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial){
                    GameObject prop = Instantiate(propPreFab, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
                }
                else{
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I've also attached a picture to demonstrate the behavior I'm seeing.
[image: Behavior]

Comment: See the code example in this answer
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/291853/raycasthit-triangleindex-and-submeshes-which-subme.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, as soon as I ask and sleep on the problem I'm able to figure it out. Arman's link was helpful as well. The issue I was seeing was caused by my not fully understanding the data I was getting from the triangleIndex call.
When calling triangleIndex you receive a vertex index back. To get the triangle  hit from that vertex you must multiply the vertex index by 3 and then validate which subMesh was struck by the raycast.